# Virtual dimesion and index?

Tags: algebraic-topology

I was told that the virtual dimension (not sure if it is virtual cohomology dimension) is equal to the index of certain operators on a manifold. Does anyone know more about this possible relation? Please point out some reference if possible. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

In certain situations (for example in gauge theory), you are considering the set of (gauge equivalence classes of) solutions to a certain system of partial differential equations. Now typically your PDE can be written as  $F(u) = 0$, where $F$ a smooth map of Banach spaces
$$F: \mathscr{X} \longrightarrow \mathscr{Y}.$$
Hence the solution set of your PDE is $F^{-1}(0) \subset \mathscr{X}$. In the important examples $F$ will be a **Fredholm map**, so that $dF$ has finite-dimensional kernel and cokernel. It turns out that $\mathrm{Ind}(dF_x) = \dim \ker(dF_x) = \dim \operatorname{coker}(dF_x)$ is independent of the choice of $x \in \mathscr{X}$, so that $F$ has a well-defined **Fredholm index**
$$\mathrm{Ind}(F) = \mathrm{Ind}(dF_x)$$
where $x \in \mathscr{X}$ is arbitrarily chosen. Now the implicit function theorem for Banach manifolds states that if $y \in \mathscr{Y}$ is a regular value of $F$, then $F^{-1}(y)$ is a Banach manifold of dimension $\mathrm{Ind}(F)$.

So what is this virtual dimension? If everything works out right, then the dimension of the solution space is simply $\mathrm{Ind}(F)$. Some things can go wrong, however. First, if $0$ is not a regular value of $F$, then the solution space $F^{-1}(0)$ might not be a manifold, but even if it is, it might not have dimension $\mathrm{Ind}(F)$. On the other hand, it might turn out that $0 \in \mathscr{Y}$ is a regular value of $F$ simply because $F^{-1}(0) = \varnothing$. Since $\varnothing$ can be a manifold of any dimension (it trivially satisfies the definition of $n$-manifold for any $n$), this isn't very helpful. So since our PDE might not have any solutions at all, we need to *perturb* the equation and instead look at $F^{-1}(y)$ for some $y$ near $0$ in $\mathscr{Y}$. This is where things can get hairy: some of the $y$'s near zero might not be regular values, and hence while $F^{-1}(y)$ might still be a manifold, it might not have dimension $\mathrm{Ind}(F)$.

The thing that saves us here is the Sard-Smale theorem. It says that the set of regular values of $F$ is **residual** in $\mathscr{Y}$ (*i.e.* it is the countable intersection of open dense subsets of $\mathscr{Y}$). So for a *generic* choice of perturbation $y \in \mathscr{Y}$ near $0$, we get that $F^{-1}(y)$ is a manifold of dimension $\mathrm{Ind}(F)$. So we call $\mathrm{Ind}(F)$ the **virtual dimension** (or expected dimension) of the space of solutions to the PDE because we may need to perturb the PDE, and for some choices of perturbation the solution space may have the wrong dimension. Since things work for a generic choice of perturbation, we are satisfied, and the invariants we construct from the topology of the solution spaces will end up not depending of the choice of generic perturbation.

Comment: Thank you Henry! This is a very nice illustration, though it takes some time to digest. In fact, I am looking for a method to compute the index of a Fredholm operator on a manifold with boundary. The APS theorem tells me that I have to compute the eta invariant of the operator on the boundary. Do you know, with the help of virtual dimension, can I avoid computing the eta invariant?

Comment: And the context is SU(2) gauge theory:)